# Google App Engine PHP 7 (standard) error log request

Tags: php, google-app-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-app-engine-php

With php 5.5 app engine standard, errors showed in Stackdriver with the request meta data (see screenshot):
[image]

With php 7 standard, no meta data:
[image]

How can I link the request meta data to the error with app engine php 7 standard?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the data that you need in the Stackdriver Logging. As it is stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/writing-application-logs) :

> When a request is sent to your application running in App Engine, request and response details are logged automatically, and can be viewed in the Google Cloud Console Stackdriver Logging Logs Viewer.

You just need to go to [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) and match the error that was reported. Than click on `expand` and you will see all the data associated to the problematic request.

You can also [configure the views for the logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/writing-application-logs#related-app-logs), in order to make them more, or less detailes, or to define their priorities. Moreover, you can write your own logs with all the data that you want to include within them :

> When your application handles a request, it can write its own logging messages to stdout and stderr. Write your application logs using stdout for output and stderr for errors. These files are automatically collected and can be viewed in the Logs Viewer.

Comment: Thank you.  I know I can still find the request by digging in the logs, but with PHP 5.5 it was so easy to see the request url that caused an error.

When I use the standard stderr all works fine with php 5.5, but php 7 standard outputs this to the logs: `[error] 20#20: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: ErrorException: Undefined variable: `...  Because of that extra text before "PHP Fatal error", Stack Driver doesn't know it's an error and it just shows as a standard log message.

Comment: This is considered intended behaviour, as you can check here - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144573569 . They will be logged, but they will never appear as "errors" in Stackdriver,

Comment: Bummer.  So is it possible at all to have stack driver report the request url with the error using php 7 standard?

Comment: Yes. The logs, exceptions thrown are reported to Stackdriver Logging, but they do not appear under the "error" label. All the necessary data should be there.

Comment: But looking at my original screenshot, there is no way to have the request url listed in the stack driver error using php7, is that correct?

Comment: Hi Adam, I think the best practice would be to catch the errors in the your code and log them to Stackdriver Logging. Apart from that each request to your app is logged in Stackdriver so you can inspect the log and check which one has produced the error looking by the timestamp.